# UWP localdata is removed when updating app, Why?

Tags: uwp

My application saved setting (sqlite) in UWP local folder.  (sideloaded)

When I update new version ( **Example 1.0.1 --> 1.0.2** ),
All sqlite file was removed.. User have to configure from beginning.

**Question**

How to avoid removing files when Update ?

**Update 1**

1. With VS2017, I make Sideload app with a version ( Ex 1.0.34 ).
2. Install it to another PC with Normal installation.I just click "AppName_1.0.34.0_x64.appxbundle" file. Windows 10 installed and start application.
3. and I repeat same step. I make another updated version ( Ex 1.0.35 ).
4. and install again.. and We know setuped SQLite file was removed.

Comment: Is it a sideloaded app? If it is, please describe here the update process step-by-step.

Comment: I updated step. Thank you !

Comment: Don't mention it. What about other files in local folder, those that are not related to SQLite? Are they also deleted during an update?

Comment: How did the SQLite database get there in the first place? Typically there is a first-run step that creates or copies the file from the app. Is there a bug there? Please post that code.

Comment: I try to update but my folder keep.

Comment: @KazuhikoNakayama please check this : right click on project and select properties > debug section > start option tab > unchecked **Uninstall and then re-install my package** If it has already been active.

Comment: the check is not checked...I will gather more information.. thank you many !